# How to Implement Login Throttling with Spring Security?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, throttling

I'm trying to find out how to throttle logins (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570160/throttling-login-attempts) with Spring Security. Does anybody has some idea?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this write-up](http://www.harinair.com/2010/02/spring-acegi-security-account-lockout/) where the author programmaticaly implements an account lockout policy based on the number of failed login attempts.  Perhaps a variation of this is what you need?